# How to make grid column non editable on the UI only - can set value using code

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How do I make a kendo grid column non-editable on client UI only but I can set a value for it in my script ?

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: result,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            IsSelected:{type:"boolean",editable:true},
                            InvoiceDate: { type: "date",editable:false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

kendo Grid

```
$('#grdClaim').kendoGrid({
    height: "300px",
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filterable: true,
    editable:true,
    columns: [
        {
            sortable: false,
            filterable: false,
            width: '30px',
            field: "IsSelected",
            title: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onclick='checkAll()'checked/>",
            template: '<input type="checkbox"  id="selectedIds"  name="selectedIds"  #= IsSelected ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" #  class="chkbx"/> ',
        }]});
```

What I need to do is to make field "IsSelected" editable on my Js code without being able to edit its value on the grid ? Like:

```
var grid = $("#grdClaim").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    dataItem.set("IsSelected", $(e.target).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);
```

Note : I'm using kendo 2013

Comment: Help me understand. You want to programatically set to `editable: false` the column `isSelected`. Am I right ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown , Not quit right , I want isSelected field to be editable programatically but readonly on the grid. and kendoGrid is `editable:true`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown the main problem is when the user click the `td` which contains my template it transforms to another checkbox not my template !

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo at dojo.telerik.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set **disabled** attribute in the template like below to make column non-editable

```
columns: [
    {
        sortable: false,
        filterable: false,
        width: '30px',
        field: "IsSelected",
        title: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onclick='checkAll()'checked/>",
        template: '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"  id="selectedIds"  name="selectedIds"  #= IsSelected ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" #  class="chkbx"/> ',
    }]
```

Comment: `disabled="disabled"` will make template useless , I want template to work, and when the end user click the `td` which contains my template , kendoGrid editing capability to be disabled

Comment: I wish something like `editable:false` on the column level not schema level,,
`columns: [
    {
       editable:false
     }]`